# Derivative with respect to $y$ and $x$ are equal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation

> Consider the wave equation $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = a^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$.  Show that $u(x,y) = \sin(y-ax)$ is a solution of the wave equation.  More generally, show that $u(x,y) = f(x-ay) + g(x+ay)$ satisfies the wave equation.

Hi, so in this problem for the second part, I got $f_{xx}(x-ay)+g_{xx}(x-ay)$ for the left hand side and
$a^2( f_{yy}(x-ay)+g_{yy}(x-ay))$ for the right hand side and I don't get why the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ have to be equal or am I confusing and the $x$ and $y$ don't matter when taking the derivative of the whole thing?

Comment: “or am i confusing and the x and y don't matter when taking the derivative of the whole thing?” <— it’s that. f and g are functions of one variable and you just have the derivative with respect to that variable. You could try to write $f(t)$, $g(t)$ when defining the functions and write $f_{tt}$, $g_{tt}$ when making the two sides of the equation explicit to be less confused.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $f$ is a function of one variable, so when you compute $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ you should get $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = f'(x-ay)+g'(x+ay)$$ instead of $$f_{x}(x-ay) + g_{x}(x+ay).$$

Comment: thankuu so muchh that makes sense. So it's like we differentiate wrt variable which the u function is in and then just multiply with the derivative of the inside thing right?

Comment: Yes, you got it!